# What genre is "Appreciate" by Paul McCartney?

Tags: similar-artists, identify-this-genre

> What musicians/bands have songs that sound like Appreciate by Paul McCartney?

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Aq-iiDXo7I) is the youtube link.

I doesn't sound like anything else that McCartney did to me. I think it's more of some kind of R&B with tinges of electronica. And lots of drums!

**EDIT:**
Mick Jagger's Sweet Thing comes to mind but again it's more of an exception to the rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fairly standard pop rock song with some (for McCartney) imaginative vocal and keyboard effects. These touches, in themselves, do not substantiate a shift in genre.

The closest example that that immediately springs to mind is [Flash And The Pan - Waiting For A Train](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aUB1VPjLGvk).